# How to define different style for same layout according to screen size?

Tags: android

How to define different style for same layout according to screen size.

Is there any way to define such thing, except from different layout folder for different screen size.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't found any other way to support different screen.

Use different folder for different screen resource:

```
ldpi    Resources for low-density (ldpi) screens (~120dpi).
mdpi    Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi). (This is the baseline  density.)
hdpi    Resources for high-density (hdpi) screens (~240dpi).
xhdpi   Resources for extra high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi).
```

You better have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can have different values folder as you have different layout folder

such as values-large, values-land, values-large-land